# DIV Element Not Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

[Take a look at this](http://minte.ryanlin.net/).

Sign in with any random username and start spamming chat till you get to the bottom of the DIV. Notice how it doesn't scroll? I need to figure out why.

***JavaScript code used for scrolling***:

```
// Note: CHATBOX_ID = "#chat"
Minte.UI.addChatEntry = function(html)
{
    // Add the chat entry... 
    var entry = '<div>' + this.formatString(html) + '</div>'; 
    $(CHATBOX_ID).html($(CHATBOX_ID).html() + entry); 

    // .. Then scroll down to the bottom
    var chatContentHeight = 0; 
    var chatHeight = $(CHATBOX_ID).height(); 

    $(CHATBOX_ID + " > div").each(function() {
        chatContentHeight += $(this).outerHeight(); 
    }); 

    if (chatContentHeight > chatHeight)
    {   
        var scroll = chatContentHeight - chatHeight; 
        $(CHATBOX_ID).scrollTop(scroll); 
    }
};
```

***And here is my CSS for #chat: ***

```
chat    {
        position: absolute; 
        left: 0%; 
        top: 0%; 
        width: 65%; 
        height: 100%;   
        text-align: left; 
        overflow-y: scroll; 
        overflow-x: hide; 
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

I have a feeling that it's happening because #chat is absolutely positioned, but I don't know why exactly. The HTML code is rather long so I didn't post it here, but on the page I linked you just view it with View Source.

I have spent too much time trying to fix this problem to no avail. Hopefully you guys can help me solve this mysterious problem.

Comment: I check the link which was given by you. Its scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.scrollHeight` property on your `#chat` element is what you want.

```
$(CHATBOX_ID).scrollTop($(CHATBOX_ID)[0].scrollHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(CHATBOX_ID).scrollTop($(CHATBOX_ID).height())
```

Comment: `.height()` gives you the visible height of the element - not the scrollable height.

Comment: yeah but it should scroll it to the bottom. You don;t need to calculate the exact amount needed to scroll

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be taking the difference between the two heights. Just scroll to the height of the larger element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `chatContentHeight` ends up at 462, while `chatHeight` is 480. Because of this, the last `if` statement is false.

There's a much simpler way to do this using jQuery. It's a bit long to paste here so here is the link: http://kisdigital.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/using-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-revised/

Answer (score 0):

or you can call some huge number like

```
$("#chat").scrollTop(1e5)
```